# how to unlink storage of laravel in window?

Tags: laravel, storage

I'm moving my project from one system to another in which storage is not working properly. i need to refresh the link of storage but when itry **php artisan storage:link** it says already linked. But i need to refresh it what is should do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
php artisan storage:link
```

The above command will create symbolic link in `public/storage` from `storage/app/public`

so when you move laravel project to new server then remove generated symbolic link folder from `public/storage`

[image]

Also, make sure to delete only the symbolic link folder not the original content also . Sometimes in Filezilla, it asks to choose the option to delete the original file also.

[image]

Another better option is not to move the symbolic link folder to a new server so you can create new symbolic link to storage folder